# How to achieve wave effect in FabricJS text

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to achieve a similar wave effect on fabric text objects. I don't have any idea how I can achieve it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
      canvas.setWidth(900);
      canvas.setHeight(500);
      canvas.set({ backgroundColor: "#FFC0CC" });

      var text = new fabric.Textbox("Hello, Fabric.js!", {
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fill: "black",
      });

      canvas.add(text);

      canvas.renderAll();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Wave effect]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you're going to need to individually animate the characters of the message. I've taken a quick look at fabric's [API documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/) and [tutorial matter for animation](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2) and the following will do what you want.

Each character in "Hello, Fabric.js!" is given its own Text object that's offset by its index in the string; sorry, no kerning here. It is then given an initial time to wait, also multiplied by its index, before starting to animate. This achieves the waviness.

Finally, fabric animations provide an event for when animations finish. `animateA` and `animateB` are just displacements up and down that call one another on that event.

The characters will desynchronize eventually, especially if not in the active tab. Something with stronger animation chops like tween.js would give you repeatable paths and timing groups, although it's *best* done with a little Math.sin and the bare canvas API.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas")
canvas.setWidth(900)
canvas.setHeight(500)
canvas.set({ backgroundColor: "#FFC0CC" })

var text = "Hello, Fabric.js!"
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
  var letter = new fabric.Text(text[i], {
    left: 50 + i * 20,
    top: 50,
    fontSize: 30,
    fill: "black"
  })
  setTimeout(animateA, 1e2 * i, letter)
  canvas.add(letter)
}

function animateA(target) {
  target.animate("top", "+=20", {
    duration: 2e3,
    easing: fabric.util.ease.easeInOutQuad,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: function() {
      animateB(target)
    }
  })
}

function animateB(target) {
  target.animate("top", "-=20", {
    duration: 2e3,
    easing: fabric.util.ease.easeInOutQuad,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: function() {
      animateA(target)
    }
  })
}

canvas.renderAll()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```